# Как сделать так чтобы при перелистывании на последней странице появилась кнопка и по клику на нее приложение закрывалось?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Данные:

1. Есть простенькое приложение презентации мобильного приложения.
   Сделано на `UIPageView`.
2. Есть приветственный экран "Welcome" (показывается после того как
   пользователь свайпнул последний скрин презентации или нажал кнопку
   "Закрыть презентацию" на последнем скрине презентации)
3. Есть контроллер `UIPageView` через который определяются в коде (в
   storyboard только один контроллер который отвечает за отображение
   этих скринов при перелистывании презентации) следующие скрины.

Также в приложении стоит параметр специального ключа который запоминает что юзер вошел уже с этим приложением и при следующем входе презентация показываться не будет, вместо нее только скрин "Welcome".(Для того чтобы зайти заново в презентацию приложения, необходимо удалить аппку из телефона/симулятора и заново перезапустить по кнопке "Run" в Xcode)

Задача:

- На последнем скрине при перелистывании должна появится кнопка "Закрыть презентацию"(при клике на нее презентация слайдов закрывается и появляется экран "Welcome").
  Cейчас там кнопка не показывается и при перелистывании после последнего слайда сразу свайпом идет скрин "Welcome".

Ссылка на само приложение тут - [Github ветка приложения](https://github.com/ViJane-dev/UI_Kit_iOS-Apps/tree/UIPageView)

Прикрепляю скриншот:
[image: картинка ситуации в IDE XCode]

Прикрепляю на всякий случай код для быстрого ознакомления:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //this method allows to call the method startPresentation
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        /*
         the viewDidAppear method is triggered immediately after the application is loaded, after the View is displayed on the screen
         */
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        startPresentation()
        
    }
    
    
    // method which runs PageViewController
  func startPresentation(){
        
        // extend realization for special key when presentation is closed
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let presentationWasViewed = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "presentationWasViewed")
        
        if presentationWasViewed == false {
            if let pageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PageViewController") as? PageViewController {
                
                // if we could show ViewController, - we need show View Controller
                present(pageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
                //попытка вывести кнопку на последний скрин
                //ContentViewController.closePresentationAction()
            }
        }
        

    }

 
    /*
    func startPresentation(){
        
            if let pageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PageViewController") as? PageViewController {
                
                // if we could show ViewController, - we need show View Controller
                present(pageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
    }
*/
    
}
```

ContentViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var presentTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emojiLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var closePresentationButton: UIButton!
    
    //let tapPresentation = UIPageViewController()
    
    
    var presentText = ""
    var emoji = ""
    var currentPage = 0 // number of the current page
    var numberOfPages = 0 // total number of pages
    
  
    var closePresButton: UIButton? // переменная для вывода кнопки на глобальный уровень
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //кнопка изначально скрыта (пока не дойдет до последнего скрина)
        closePresentationButton.isHidden = true
        
        
        presentTextLabel.text = presentText
        emojiLabel.text = emoji
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage
        
        closePresentationButton = closePresButton
        
        //еще раз попытка показать скрытую кнопку именно на последнем скрине
        //closePresentationButton.isHidden = false
    }
    
    //тут кнопка которая должна появится при просмотре последнего скрина

    @IBAction func closePresentationAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let closePresentation = PageViewController()
        closePresentation.closePresentationButtonFunc()
        
    }

}
```

PageViewContrller.swift

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    let presentScreenContent = [
    "Первая страница презентации, - рассказывает о сути приложения",
    "Вторая страница презентации, - рассказывает о какой-то фишке приложения",
    "Третья страница презентации, - показывает еще что-то очен интересное в виде картинки и анимации",
    "Последяя страница презентации, - какое-то приятное пожелание пользователю", ""
    
    ]
    
    let emojiArray = [
    "","‍","","", ""
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        // we need to assign the class as a delegate of the protocol datasource
        dataSource = self

        //declare method ContentViewController
        if let contentViewController = showViewControllerAtIndex(0){
            
            //method which create array of the View Controllers
            setViewControllers([contentViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
        }
        
        closePresentationButtonFunc()
    }
    
  
    //method which allows for us to create ViewController
    func showViewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> ContentViewController? {
        
        guard index >= 0 else { return nil }
        guard index < presentScreenContent.count else { return nil }
        guard let contentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ContentViewController")
                as? ContentViewController else { return nil }
        contentViewController.presentText = presentScreenContent[index]
        contentViewController.emoji = emojiArray[index]
        contentViewController.currentPage = index
        contentViewController.numberOfPages = presentScreenContent.count
        
        //contentViewController.buttonForClose = closePresentationButtonFunc
        
        // пока оно выводит просто свайпом закрытие презентации
        if contentViewController.currentPage == presentScreenContent.count-1{
            closePresentationButtonFunc()
            
        }
       
        return contentViewController
    }
    
    //функция которая работает с параметрами закрытия презентации
    func closePresentationButtonFunc(){
           
            //-------------
            //сreating a key that allows you to save the state of the presentation before it closes
            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "presentationWasViewed")
            
        
            //method which close controller
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            //------------
    }
    
}



extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        // get number of current page
        var pageNumber = (viewController as! ContentViewController).currentPage
        
        pageNumber -= 1
        
        return showViewControllerAtIndex(pageNumber)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        // get number of current page
        var pageNumber = (viewController as! ContentViewController).currentPage
        
        pageNumber += 1
        
        return showViewControllerAtIndex(pageNumber)
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я посмотрел проект и внес ряд правок (см комментарии). По поводу видимости кнопки - я добавил переменную `presentationButtonIsHidden`, которая присваивается при инициализации очередного контроллера, это происходит раньше, чем отрабатывает `viewDidLoad`, поэтому затем эту переменную можно использовать как `closePresentationButton.isHidden = presentationButtonIsHidden`

```
class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var presentTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emojiLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var closePresentationButton: UIButton!

    var presentText = ""
    var emoji = ""
    var currentPage = 0 // number of the current page
    var numberOfPages = 0 // total number of pages
    
    var presentationButtonIsHidden = true // -- 1 добавлена переменная
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //кнопка изначально скрыта (пока не дойдет до последнего скрина)
        closePresentationButton.isHidden = presentationButtonIsHidden // -- 2 присваиваем
        
        presentTextLabel.text = presentText
        emojiLabel.text = emoji
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage
    }
    
    //тут кнопка которая должна появится при просмотре последнего скрина

    @IBAction func closePresentationAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // -- 3 закрываем презентацию
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "presentationWasViewed")
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

---

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    // -- 1 убрана пустая страница
    let presentScreenContent = [
    "Первая страница презентации, - рассказывает о сути приложения",
    "Вторая страница презентации, - рассказывает о какой-то фишке приложения",
    "Третья страница презентации, - показывает еще что-то очен интересное в виде картинки и анимации",
    "Последяя страница презентации, - какое-то приятное пожелание пользователю"
    
    ]
    // -- 2 убрана пустая страница
    let emojiArray = [
    "","‍","",""
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        // we need to assign the class as a delegate of the protocol datasource
        dataSource = self

        //declare method ContentViewController
        if let contentViewController = showViewControllerAtIndex(0){
            
            //method which create array of the View Controllers
            setViewControllers([contentViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
        }
    }
    
  
    //method which allows for us to create ViewController
    func showViewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> ContentViewController? {
        
        guard index >= 0 else { return nil }
        guard index < presentScreenContent.count else { return nil }
        guard let contentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ContentViewController")
                as? ContentViewController else { return nil }
        contentViewController.presentText = presentScreenContent[index]
        contentViewController.emoji = emojiArray[index]
        contentViewController.currentPage = index
        contentViewController.numberOfPages = presentScreenContent.count
        
        let isLastPage = (index == presentScreenContent.count - 1)
        contentViewController.presentationButtonIsHidden = !isLastPage // -- 3 управляем видимостью кнопки
        
        return contentViewController
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за внимание и разбор моего проекта. Все заработало. Теперь сижу и разбираю построчно вариант решения :) Благодаря Вам я узнала свои ошибки и где моя логика уходила немного не в ту сторону. У меня появилась осознанность как правильно делать переключения между элементами интерфейса. Буду практиковаться дальше! Еще раз Вам выражаю свою признательность!

Comment: @ВикторияРоманюк рад что помог